# Sum of 2 consecutive integers is $x$ then their product will be?

Tags: integers

According to a source, the answer is
 $x^2-\frac{1}{4}$

Please explain

Comment: $$a+a+1=x\iff a=\dfrac{x-1}2$$

We need $a(a+1)$

Comment: Your source has a typo.  It should be $\frac{x^2 - 1}4$ rather than $x^2 - \frac 14$

Comment: Think about it.  Suppose the consecutive numbers are n and m.  Then x = n + m.  This is an integer.  $n*m$ is also an integer.  As is $x^2$  But $x^2 - 1/4$ is never an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the consecutive integers be $a$,$a+1$...

Now,$a+(a+1)=x\implies a=\frac{x-1}{2}\implies (a+1)=\frac{x+1}{2}$

Hence, $a(a+1)=\frac{x-1}{2}*\frac{x+1}{2}=\frac{x^2-1}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the first of those consecutive numbers.
Then we have:
$$ n + (n+1) = x $$

which implies $ n= \frac{x-1}{2}$

using that you can calculate the product of $n(n+1)$

Comment: According to this, the answer would be $\frac{x^2-1}{4}$

Comment: Yep.  Someone at the source made the all to common editing error of writing $\frac{x^2 - 1}{4}=x^2 - 1/4 = x^2 - \frac 14$.  So your source has a typo.

Comment: @fleablood It doesn´t seem that your guess is right.

Comment: What guess?  I didn't guess at anything.  The solution is wrong.  Take 7+8 = 15.  7 x 8 = 56 = (225 - 1)/4 $\ne$ 255 - 1/4.